# SystemVerilog - using $bits

Tags: system-verilog

I have a question that I coudlnt find an answer to in the LRM.
if we declare a signal, for example logic a;
then we declare a signal 'b', in this way:
logic [$bits(a)-1:0] b;

does signal 'a' should be considered as read signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$bits(expr)`, the expression’s value is never evaluated or *read*. The number of bits returned is based only on the statically determined type of the resulting expression.”

If the expression is made from statically sized variables, the the result from `$bits` can be used as a constant expression as you have done here to declare another variable. But if the expression is dynamically-sized (a queue or dynamic array), then the result is dynamic and cannot be used as a constant expression. But still, the contents of the array are never *read*.